Additivity of the integration set
Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure and take $A\in \mathcal{M}$.
Consider $f:A\to [-\infty,+\infty]$.
Def. Suppose that $\mu(X\setminus A)=0$. Then, $f$ is said definite almost everywhere on X.
If $g:X\to [-\infty,+\infty]$ is a measurable extension of $f$, then we have

$\int_{X\setminus A} g \ d\mu=0$.

$\int_X g \ d\mu=\int_A g\ d\mu + \int_{X\setminus A} g\ d\mu$.


The first point follows from lebesgue integral's properties.
The following is my attempt to prove the second point:
$$\int_X g\ d\mu=\int_X g^+\ d\mu-\int_X g^-\ d\mu=\int_A g^+\ d\mu+\int_{X\setminus A} g^+\ d\mu -\left(\int_A g^-\ d\mu+\int_{X\setminus A} g^-\ d\mu\right)=$$ $$=\int_A g^+\ d\mu-\int_{A} g^-\ d\mu + \int_{X\setminus A} g^+\ d\mu-\int_{X\setminus A} g^-\ d\mu=\int_A g \ d\mu+\int_{X\setminus A} g\ d\mu$$
So, if this is correct, can I say that $\int_X g\ d\mu=\int_A f\ d\mu$ under the previous hypothesis?

Its look correct, but I dont undestand why you descompose $g$ into the positive and negative parts. Why you cant directly write $X = X \cup X \backslash A$ and then use that $X$ and $X \backslash A$ are disjoint sets?

Because my teacher suggests me to use the definition of Lebesgue integral, but yes, it's quicker using that $X=A\cup X\setminus A$.

However, what about the fact $\int_X g\ d\mu =\int_A f\ d\mu$?

@SigmaAlgebra You probably defined the Lebesgue integral on a measurable subset $A\in\mathcal M$ as $\int_X _A f d\mu$. Your teacher probably wanted to hint to you that  $\int_X f d\mu = \int_X _X f d\mu = \int_X _A f+ _{X\setminus A}f  d\mu $

Yes, it's clear in this way too. So, the conclusion is to prove that if $\mu(X\setminus A)=0$, then $\int_X f\ d \mu=\int_A f \ d\mu$? In particular, does this mean that $\int_ X g\ d\mu=\int_A f\ d\mu$?

Yes, in the bounde case:
$\lvert \int_A f d \mu \lvert = \int_A \lvert f \lvert d \mu \leq \mu(A) max f = 0$.
In the unbounde case, is usualy a convention. The way I think this is to consider a sequent of bounde function ${ f_n }_n$ converging to $f$ and then use some limit-integral theorem.

I come back, in the unbound case you can do this:
Define $f_n = max(n, |f|) _{(-n,n)}$. Then is clear that all $f_n$ are bounds (with distincts bounds) and $f_n \rightarrow f$. Also is clear that $f_n \leq f_m$ for all $n \leq m$ so we can apply the monote converge theorem:
$$0 = \lim_n 0 = \lim_n \int_A f_n d \mu = \int_A \lim_n f_n d \mu = \int_A f d \mu, $$ where the second equality is because $f_n$ is bounded.
